# Dialect that voices "achtzig" as "achtlig" or "achtling"

Tags: dialect, history, swiss-german

About 25 years ago I was traveling in a remote part of Graubünden, Switzerland, and I noticed at a kiosk that the elderly woman behind the counter voiced multiples of ten as ending in "lig" or maybe "ling" rather than "zig".

What dialect could this have been?

I don't remember exactly where I was, but I think it was in the far south of Graubünden, not far from the Italian border.

Comment: You need to consider that this might not even be dialect but a personal quirk. My own grandmother (who grew up in a rural area in the 1910s and 1920s and had the corresponding low education and also spoke Märkisches Plattdeutsch as a child) always said "fumpzich" instead of "fünfzich". I have never met another person who did so. The region you describe would hint at Walserdeutsch but I couldn't find examples of how they say numbers above ten. Being from Northern Germany, I don't think I'd be able to understand that dialect at all. So I wonder if she even spoke her dialect to you.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently in Graubünden they speak 5 dialects of Rätoromansch and according to this page (https://de.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Sprachf%C3%BChrer_R%C3%A4toromanisch) they pronounce 20 as ventg, which maybe is pronounced as "tig," but that ending doesn't hold true for 30, 40, etc.

Comment: Romansh is a Romance language, one of the four official languages of Switzerland. The question was about dialects of German. At least I think that the OP would have recognised the difference.

Comment: True, we were speaking German and I can't understand any Romansch, but maybe the particular word comes from there. Walserdeutsch seems like the more likely option to me, but obv I have no idea.